# Getting the exact number of frames from movie clip

Tags: iphone, c, ios, video, video-processing

Im building an iphone app for video analyzing and i need to know the exact amount of frames in the movie clip.

I got the frame rate and the duration and for some reason i get 2880 frames but i know that the movie clip has actually 2840.

how can i get an exact number of frames?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well this will depend on the video format.

If it's raw video then PAL and SECAM dictate 25 frames per secon(fps), NTSC 29.97 actual film is 24fps. Is it interlaced or progressive scan?

Is it already compressed and hence uses an approximation of frame numbers?

**edit**

Ah so you're video is in H.264/MPEG4 standard with AAC audio? The indexing data is held within the "moov" part of the file that contains all of the indexing and data values that make up the file. For more information on the MPEG4 standard look [here](http://mpeg.chiariglione.org/standards/mpeg-4/mpeg-4.htm)

If you can extract this data it will tell you the data size of each frame etc.

Comment: Video standard and interlaced vs progressive has absolutely nothing to do with the captured number of frames.

Comment: specifically it's H.264, AAC filmed by the iPad

Comment: natko - actually it does if Or.Ron was processing raw video (YUV, RGB etc). As it is he's processing a compressed format.

Comment: Ha can open that H264 and read the number of frames from the meta data. It's not present only in some rare cases. Color format, video standard and scan type are not related to captured number of frames in any way.

Comment: As I said - only because he's processing a compressed format rather that a raw video format.

Answer (score 1):

The exact number of frames is usually written somewhere inside the file and it can be retrieved. But, the video file may contain more or less frames.
For example, you get 2880 frames and you know that you should get 2840. My guess would be that some time stamps are equal. Decoded frame with the same time stamp as the previous one should be skipped/ignored. Did you check that?
You can also get less frames that reported. It means that some frames has longer duration than expected. For example, if you have a movie clip recorded at 25 fps, the duration of one frame is 40ms. However, after decompression you might get a frame with duration 80. Such frame should really have that duration, or it could be repeated twice...

Comment: I couldn't find the total frames number in the file and the frame rate is 29.3. The point is i need to know the frame number before im starting to read through all the frames

Comment: First you wrote "I know that the movie clip has actually 2840" and now you say "I couldn't find the total frames number in the file". How did you get 2840 in the first place?? Try to decode frame by frame and display the time stamp for each decoded frame. P.S. I assume that you are reading ONLY one video stream from that video clip.

Comment: The video didn't say 2840 i counted it going through frame by frame. and yeah im reading only the video track of the movie! So basicly you are saying that there is no way to know Exact total frame number?

Comment: Yes, it is possible. For example, ffmpeg will tell you the number of frames for any valid H.264 video clip.

Comment: So how do u think this tool implements it ? just (duration) * (fps) ?

Comment: Yes, but that's only an estimate. Did you try to obtain the number of frames from the metadata (if it is available)?

Comment: No, im just working on it. It tells me that the available metadata types are : `com.apple.quicktime.udta` and `com.apple.quicktime.mdta`

Comment: Is there something like GetMediaSampleCount() API available in your environment? If it is, what does it return for video track?

Answer (score 0):

here is another good answer of **Rhythmic Fistman** at [iOS Determine Number of Frames in Video](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29506411/ios-determine-number-of-frames-in-video). it in SWIFT but i've tried like bellow(Objective-C):

```
- (void)getTotalFramesFromVideo{
    AVURLAsset* asset = [AVURLAsset assetWithURL:URL1];
    NSError* errReader=nil;
    AVAssetReader* reader = [AVAssetReader assetReaderWithAsset:asset error:&errReader];
    if(!errReader){
        AVAssetTrack* track = [asset tracksWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo].firstObject;
        AVAssetReaderOutput* readerOutput = [AVAssetReaderTrackOutput assetReaderTrackOutputWithTrack:track outputSettings:nil];
        [reader addOutput:readerOutput];
        [reader startReading];
        long long count = 0;
        BOOL isAvailable = NO;
        do {
            CMSampleBufferRef ref = [readerOutput copyNextSampleBuffer];
            if(ref){
                isAvailable = YES;
                count++;
            }else{
                isAvailable = NO;
            }
        } while (isAvailable == YES);
        NSLog(@"Total Frames in your Video is %@",@(count));
    }else{
        NSLog(@"\nAVAssetReaderError:\n%@",errReader.localizedDescription);
    }
}
```

this might be helpful to someone like me who wants to get frame count of Video.
NOTE: you can also get `CMSampleBufferRef` in this method.

Answer (score 0):

The real way to calculate the number of frames is to query the frame duration and then divide the total movie duration in seconds by the frame duration. The suggestion to read all the frames is too slow to actually be used for anything but short videos. There is also the problem of delta frames in a H.264 stream. You can query the track length via AVAssetTrack.timeRange and then the frame duration can be queried via AVAssetTrack.minFrameDuration. An example of working source code that does this calculation can be found [here](https://github.com/mdejong/H264AlphaPlayer/blob/master/H264AlphaPlayer/AVAnimator/AVAssetFrameDecoder.m#L204). Note that these CMTime values need to be turned into floating point time values by passing them through CMTimeGetSeconds().