# iOS Determine Number of Frames in Video

Tags: ios, swift, video, mpmovieplayercontroller, video-processing

If I have a MPMoviePlayerController in Swift:

```
MPMoviePlayerController mp = MPMoviePlayerController(contentURL: url)
```

Is there a way I can get the number of frames within the video located at `url`? If not, is there some other way to determine the frame count?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I don't think `MPMoviePlayerController` can help you.

Use an `AVAssetReader` and count the number of `CMSampleBuffer`s it returns to you. You can configure it to not even decode the frames, effectively parsing the file, so it should be fast and memory efficient.

Something like

```
    var asset = AVURLAsset(URL: url, options: nil)
    var reader = AVAssetReader(asset: asset, error: nil)
    var videoTrack = asset.tracksWithMediaType(AVMediaTypeVideo)[0] as! AVAssetTrack

    var readerOutput = AVAssetReaderTrackOutput(track: videoTrack, outputSettings: nil) // NB: nil, should give you raw frames
    reader.addOutput(readerOutput)
    reader.startReading()

    var nFrames = 0

    while true {
        var sampleBuffer = readerOutput.copyNextSampleBuffer()
        if sampleBuffer == nil {
            break
        }

        nFrames++
    }

    println("Num frames: \(nFrames)")
```

Sorry if that's not idiomatic, I don't know swift.

Comment: Excellent! Do you have any quick example you could show? That would be most helpful.

Answer (score 1):

**Swift 5**

```
 func getNumberOfFrames(url: URL) -> Int {
        let asset = AVURLAsset(url: url, options: nil)
        do {
            let reader = try AVAssetReader(asset: asset)
        //AVAssetReader(asset: asset, error: nil)
            let videoTrack = asset.tracks(withMediaType: AVMediaType.video)[0]

            let readerOutput = AVAssetReaderTrackOutput(track: videoTrack, outputSettings: nil) // NB: nil, should give you raw frames
            reader.add(readerOutput)
        reader.startReading()

        var nFrames = 0

        while true {
            let sampleBuffer = readerOutput.copyNextSampleBuffer()
            if sampleBuffer == nil {
                break
            }

            nFrames = nFrames+1
        }

        print("Num frames: \(nFrames)")
            return nFrames
        }catch {
            print("Error: \(error)")
        }
        return 0
    }
```

Comment: be sure to set the settings, or you might get a wrong number. `let readerSettings = [String(kCVPixelBufferPixelFormatTypeKey): Int(kCVPixelFormatType_32BGRA)]` will do

Answer (score 0):

You could also use frames per second to calculate total frames.

```
var player: AVPlayer?
var playerController = AVPlayerViewController()
var videoFPS: Int = 0
var totalFrames: Int?


guard let videoURL = "" else { return }
player = AVPlayer(url: videoURL)
playerController.player = player
guard player?.currentItem?.asset != nil else {
    return
}
let asset = self.player?.currentItem?.asset
let tracks = asset!.tracks(withMediaType: .video)
let fps = tracks.first?.nominalFrameRate
let duration = self.player?.currentItem?.duration

self.videoFPS = lround(Double(fps!))
self.totalFrames = lround(Double(self!.videoFPS) * durationSeconds)
```

Comment: if the video is encoded with variable frame rate, this solution will give an estimate, not the exact value.